# How can I keep an office chair cool enough to avoid causing perspiration?

Tags: furniture, temperature, office

I'm in an office environment. Like many office workers, I have a chair! When I'm sitting in said chair, my body heat seems to get absorbed by the glorious, cushiony, cloth-covered padding I'm sitting on.  This makes me sweat, and it isn't comfortable!

So, what methods are there to cool the chair down while I'm sitting on it to prevent it from becoming too warm?

Comment: I see a downvote, as best I can tell this is a relevant question. Please let me know if this is is an inappropriate question for the site.

Comment: Can you replace the chair?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see if you can get a seat mat made from bamboo, like this one 
[image: bamboo cover mat]

They work well for keeping your body cool.

Comment: I actually have one on order! I was thinking that there may be other alternative solutions that I hadn't thought of that are more along the lines of a lifehack instead of a product. Hopefully it will solve my problem. When I get it, if nobody has answered by then I'll probably accept this unless I come up with something else.

Answer (score 1):

Get up and move. Even if just standing at your desk, you'll get some airflow to cool you and the chair off. Go get some water or something else that can be done quickly. I've never tried the bamboo cover, though they look uncomfortable to me.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a towel on the chair can be helpful. I use one made of [microfiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microfiber) as it works best for me. Microfiber is especially good at absorbing moisture from both sides, and is often used in sportswear to wick away perspiration.

I recommend it for your application because keeping your chair dry can help it feel cooler.  If you're worried about appearance, microfiber's very thin, and can go unnoticed by co-workers. Even if they see the towel, it tends to be fairly unobtrusive. Since it comes in many colors, you can choose something that closely matches your chair. The material is easy to cut, and doesn't easily fray, so you can size it as you see fit.

I keep a number of these towels around the house, as they're good for many things. If you don't happen to have any, they're inexpensive (at least here in Northeast United States), and can be found at a variety of stores.  Best of all, they wash easily and last a very long time.

Comment: Buy a better office chair, many of them have backs made of a thin mesh-like material that facilitate air flow. Acquiring one of those would solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

get up every 40 minutes or so and walk around, also you could try using baby powder.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Get a cooling seat which can be layed on the seat. Search in Amazon.

Option 2: Take a break for walking on stairs(if available)

Option 3: Do streching at desk.

Option 4. If none of the above work. Move to the front edge of the seat, Lift your butt & Balance on thighs for once in an hour for few mins.

Comment: The first three options have already been given as answers.